# Moving to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 and spring-boot-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm trying to move my application to move to Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4

Everything is going fine right now except one issue with spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.0.0.M4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

This is plugin declaration:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What can be wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is an `M4` released to maven central yet,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin

Add the pluginRepo,

```
   <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

to the POM

Which has the M4 milestone.

http://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.0.0.M4/

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/getting-started-installing-spring-boot.html for further details about the SNAPSHOT/Milestone repos.